# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/flurry/android/Constants,Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: android

while running android application i got error

> "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/flurry/android/Constants" and "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/flurry/android/Constants"

Comment: try `multiDexEnabled` `true` in your gradle file

Comment: Please [edit] to include your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

In dependency of your app level build.gradle add :

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

and in default config :

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: This type of answer already present in stack .please provide link in comment section instead answer